# How to skip to next value in range slider, steps only allow numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, slider

I am creating a range slider to show different venue with capacities and displaying/hidding gallery according to the range selected by the user on the slider.

my capacity are [ 50, 100, 200, 300, 500 ]

**Q1** 
I want my range slider to go the next value automatically instead of its usual steps (currently set to 50)

**Q2**
Can my slider include string instead of number, like I want to show, [Small, Medium, Large] venues there.

I am a newbie so please let me know if there is a way to do it,
Also here is the code, if there is an easier way to approach it please let me know.

Thanks a lot for your time and help

here is the code

https://jsfiddle.net/6v5dsfz3/1/

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1A77B9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Slide for Required Capacity for Grounds</h2>

<div class="slidecontainer">
  <!-- input will go here -->
  <p>Venue Capacity: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<div class='venue' data-capacity=60>
Venue C has capacity of 60

</div>

<div class='venue' data-capacity=70>
Venue Q has capacity of 70
</div>

<div class='venue' data-capacity=400>
temp 4
</div>


<script>
    var smallCap = [50, 100, 200, 300, 500];
    var Capacity;

    var inputTemplate = '<input id="myRange" class="slider" type="range" min={min} max={max} value={value} step="1">'
    inputTemplate = inputTemplate.replace("{min}",smallCap[0]).replace("{max}",smallCap[smallCap.length-1]).replace("{value}",smallCap[0]);
    $('.slidecontainer').prepend(inputTemplate);

    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");

    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    slider.oninput = function() {
        myfunction(this.value);
    }


    function myfunction(value) {
        output.innerHTML = value;

        document.querySelectorAll('.venue').forEach(item => { item.style.display = 'none'; })

        var element = document.querySelector('.venue[data-capacity="' + value + '"]');
        if (element) {
            element.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    myfunction(smallCap[0]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have put up a well phrased question, but you are missing the code. It is impossible to tell how your slider works without seeing the code behind it.

Comment: Sorry I missed to enter to the code before, I have embedded it above now, Sorry I am new to stack overflow. 
thanks for pointing it out.